# CUDA: nested FOR-loops with 3D kernel: How to determine the position where threads should write the result?

Tags: multidimensional-array, parallel-processing, cuda, nested-loops

in the following iteration, the position in the vector "result" is determined by the "counter". Please, also look at the starting values in the FOR-loop, which shows that some iterations are left out.

```
int counter = (int)0;

for (z=0; z<N; z++)
   for (y=z; y<N; y++)
      for (x=y; x<N; x++)
      {
       
          result[counter] = A[z] + A[y] + A[x];

          counter++;
      }
```

However, if I translate this iteration into a 3d kernel I wonder how I can provide each thread with the correct position to write in the vector "result"? Is there a mathematical solution to calculate out the missing threads?

```
int idz = blockIdx.z*blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;
int idy = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

if(idx >= idy && idy >= idz)
{
    result[?????] = A[idz] + A[idy] + A[idx];
}
```

I tried to skip the missings with the Gauss equation:

```
0.5 * idx * (idx + 1)
```

But I am not even close to the solution. Does someone has an idea?

Comment: In the second loop, should y start from z, or can it start from (z+1)? can the values of x, y and z be the same?

Comment: Hi Elad, unfortunately the starting values of z, y and x in the iteration need to be like I stated in the question. After each loop some iterations are skipped and I am looking for a solution to calculate those missings in order to provide the 3d threads with the correct address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine there might be more than one way to tackle this.  I shall sketch one approach.

The formulas for the sum of the first n integers and sum of first n integers squared are [readily available](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/) as:

```
Σi   i:1..n  = (n)(n+1)/2 
Σi^2 i:1..n  = (n)(n+1)(2n+1)/6
```

Let's start by building a table showing the amount of loop iterations in `x`, for each `z,y` position.  To visualize this it will help if we choose a small number for `N`, like 4:

```
  z|  0   1   2   3
y
-
0     4
1     3   3
2     2   2   2
3     1   1   1   1
```

From the above table, we can observe that the sum of any column is the sum of the first n integers, where n can be deduced from `N` and `z` index.  (n = `N-z`).

We can use this observation, plus the formula (indicated above) for the sum of the first n integers, to compute the offset (into the result array) for a given `z` value.  This offset will be the sum of the columns to the left of `z`.   We can observe from the above pattern that the offset contributed by the `z` index is:

```
Σ(i)(i+1)/2   i: (N-z)..N
```

which is:

```
1/2 * ( Σ(i^2) + Σi)   i: (N-z)..N
```

now, summing over `(N-z)..N` is inconvenient, so to realize this using the formulas presented above, we shall rewrite each summation as the difference of two summations, one from 1..`N` minus one from 1..`z`:

```
1/2 * ( Σ(i^2)|1..N - Σ(i^2)|1..z  + Σi|1..N - Σi|1..z) )
```

If we substitute our formulas for the sums presented in the beginning into the above expression, we can come up with a closed-form expression for the offset contributed by the `z` index.

```
(((N*(N+1)*(2*N + 1) - (N-z)*(N-z+1)*(2*(N-z)+1))/3 + (N*(N+1) - (N-z)*(N-z+1)))/2
```

Now we need to come up with a formula for the offset (into the result array) contributed by the `y` index. Again, by inspection of the pattern in the `z,y` array presented earlier, we can observe that this is given by:

```
Σi   i: (N-y)..(N-z)
```

We can likewise convert this to the difference of two summations for calculation purposes, and then use our formula for the sum of the integers:

```
((N-z)(N-z+1) - (N-y)(N-y+1))/2
```

We also have to make an adjustment to the `x` index.

Here's a full example:

```
$ cat t112.cu
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void on_cpu(int N, T *A, T *result){

  int counter = 0;
  int x,y,z;
  for (z=0; z<N; z++)
    for (y=z; y<N; y++)
      for (x=y; x<N; x++){
        result[counter] = A[z] + A[y] + A[x];
        counter++;}
  std::cout << " counter = " << counter << std::endl;
}
__host__ __device__ int compute_z_offset(int N, int z){
  int i = N-z;
  // 0.5*(sum n^2|1..N - sum n^2|1..i + sum n|1..N - sum n|1..i )
  int sumn2 = ((N*(N+1)*(2*N + 1)) - (i*(i+1)*(2*i + 1)))/3;
  int sumn  = ((N*(N+1)) - (i*(i+1)));
  return (sumn2 + sumn)>>2;
}

__host__ __device__ int compute_y_offset(int N, int z, int y){
  int i = N-z;
  int j = N-y;
  return (i*(i+1) - j*(j+1))>>1;
}

template <typename T>
__global__ void on_gpu(int N, T *A, T *result){

  int idz = blockIdx.z*blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;
  int idy = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
  int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

if(idx >= idy && idy >= idz && idx < N && idy < N && idz < N){
  result[compute_z_offset(N, idz) + compute_y_offset(N, idz, idy) + (idx-idy)] = A[idz] + A[idy] + A[idx];
  }
}

int main(){

  const int N = 9;
  int *A, *result, *d_A, *d_result, *h_result;
  A = new int[N];
  result = new int[N*N*N];
  h_result = new int[N*N*N];
  cudaMalloc(&d_result, N*N*N*sizeof(result[0]));
  cudaMalloc(&d_A, N*sizeof(A[0]));
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) A[i] = i+1;
  cudaMemcpy(d_A, A, N*sizeof(A[0]), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemset(d_result, 0, N*N*N*sizeof(result[0]));
  on_cpu(N, A, result);
  dim3 block(8,8,8);
  dim3 grid((N+block.x-1)/block.x, (N+block.y-1)/block.y, (N+block.z-1)/block.z);
  on_gpu<<<grid, block>>>(N, d_A, d_result);
  cudaMemcpy(h_result, d_result, N*N*N*sizeof(result[0]), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  for (int i = 0; i < N*N*N; i++) if (result[i] != h_result[i]) {std::cout << "mismatch at: " << i << " was: " << h_result[i] << " should be: " << result[i] << std::endl; break;}
}
$ nvcc -o t112 t112.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t112
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
 counter = 165
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

I have not tested this thoroughly.  My purpose is to demonstrate how it might be done, but there may be defects.  Also, I imagine the indexing calculations perhaps could be simplified (combine like terms, etc.)  For convenience, I simply set the size of the result arrays to `N*N*N`, although not all those locations would be "used".  You can determine the necessary size analytically using the formulas I have already presented here.

Here is a slightly edited version of the code.  Mostly it is just modified to allow for testing various `N` values, but I also did some like terms combination in the z-offset calculation.  It seems to work up to `N` values of 1000, which is as far as I wanted to test.  I've also demonstrated how to pre-compute the size needed for the output array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

template <typename T>
int on_cpu(int N, T *A, T *result){

  int counter = 0;
  int x,y,z;
  for (z=0; z<N; z++)
    for (y=z; y<N; y++)
      for (x=y; x<N; x++){
        result[counter] = A[z] + A[y] + A[x];
        counter++;}
  std::cout << " N: " << N << " counter = " << counter << std::endl;
  return counter;
}
__host__ __device__ int compute_z_offset(int N, int z){
  int i = N-z;
  // 0.5*(sum n^2|1..N - sum n^2|1..i + sum n|1..N - sum n|1..i
  //int sumn2 = ((N*(N+1)*(2*N + 1)) - (i*(i+1)*(2*i + 1)))/3;
  //int sumn  = ((N*(N+1)) - (i*(i+1)));
  //return (sumn2 + sumn)>>2;
  return ((N*(N+1)*(2*N + 4)) - (i*(i+1)*(2*i + 4)))/12;
}

__host__ __device__ int compute_y_offset(int N, int z, int y){
  int i = N-z;
  int j = N-y;
  return (i*(i+1) - j*(j+1))>>1;
}

template <typename T>
__global__ void on_gpu(int N, T *A, T *result){

  int idz = blockIdx.z*blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;
  int idy = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
  int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

  if(idx >= idy && idy >= idz && idx < N && idy < N && idz < N)
  {
    result[compute_z_offset(N, idz) + compute_y_offset(N, idz, idy) + (idx-idy)] = A[idz] + A[idy] + A[idx];
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  int N = 32;
  if (argc > 1) N = atoi(argv[1]);
  int *A, *result, *d_A, *d_result, *h_result;
  A = new int[N];
  int max_N_size = compute_z_offset(N, N-1) + 1;
  result = new int[max_N_size];
  h_result = new int[max_N_size];
  cudaMalloc(&d_result, sizeof(result[0])*max_N_size);
  cudaMalloc(&d_A, N*sizeof(A[0]));
  for (int my_N = 1; my_N<N; my_N++){
    for (int i = 0; i < my_N; i++) A[i] = i+1;
    int N_size = on_cpu(my_N, A, result);
    int test_N_size = compute_z_offset(my_N, my_N-1) + 1;
    if (test_N_size != N_size) std::cout << "mismatch on size calc" << std::endl;
    cudaMemcpy(d_A, A, sizeof(A[0])*my_N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemset(d_result, 0, sizeof(result[0])*N_size);
    dim3 block(8,8,8);
    dim3 grid((my_N+block.x-1)/block.x, (my_N+block.y-1)/block.y, (my_N+block.z-1)/block.z);
    on_gpu<<<grid, block>>>(my_N, d_A, d_result);
    cudaMemcpy(h_result, d_result, sizeof(result[0])*N_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    for (int i = 0; i < N_size; i++) if (result[i] != h_result[i]) {std::cout << "mismatch at: " << i << " was: " << h_result[i] << " should be: " << result[i] << std::endl; break;}

  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant and thank you very much for your answer and effort! That helped me a lot and I will test it in the next few days thoroughly :-)